# Find elements by attribute's partial value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some `img` tags inside `iFrame`(id=iframe1) on my page.
Some of them has `src` attribute set to `myimg.jpg`, 'myimg_small.jpg', `myimg_large.jpg` etc.

I am trying to find everything inside `#iframe1` with `src` *like* `myimg`, so I wrote

```
images = $('#iframe1').contents().find('[src*="myimg"]')
```

but I am getting error as below

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   [src*="myimg"])
>
> at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-1.8.2.js:4679)
>   at tokenize (jquery-1.8.2.js:4739)
>   at select (jquery-1.8.2.js:5099)
>   at select (jquery-1.8.2.js:5276)
>   at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-1.8.2.js:3941)
>   at init.find (jquery-1.8.2.js:5372)
>   at <anonymous>:1:36

What's wrong here?

**Update**

```js
alert($('#if').contents().find('[src*="ss"]').next().html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id='if'>
  <img src='sss.jpg' />
  <div>
    scdscd
  </div>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Can you create a sample where we can debug?

Comment: You've got an extra closing parentheses there.

Comment: Your JSFiddle code is invalid HTML - Code inside iFrame tags do not magically become iFrame content - I added the code as a `<>` snippet here. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: If you want add contents to `iframe` either you have to specify URL using `src` attribute or HTML string using `srcdoc` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
var x = $("img[src$='myimg.jpg']");
alert(x.attr("src"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/), and as Enfyve mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930715/find-elements-by-attributes-partial-value/41930797#comment71041824_41930715) remove extra `)`.

```
images = $('#iframe1').contents().find('[src~="myimg"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong about using an `iframe`.
The iframe must use the `src` attribute and use it to load the contents of other pages. An iframe does not need to include its child elements directly in its tag.

You can try this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id='if' src="1.html">
</iframe>


//1.html
...
  <img src='sss.jpg' />
  <div>
    scdscd
  </div>
```

and you can try as following.

```
alert($('#iframe1').contents().find('[src*="ss"]').next().html());
```

Comment: That was just to create a sample, as I said.

Comment: @Imad, I mean, you need to use an iframe to load the contents of another page. Adding sub-tags to an iframe tag like this is useless and looks like an abuse.

Answer (score 0):

Selector is correctly working. You can see working jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/rucunuliri/edit?html,js,output).

Incorrect usage of `iframe` is causing issue for you.

If you want add contents to iframe either you have to specify URL using `src` attribute or HTML string using `srcdoc` attribute.

> The srcdoc attribute specifies the HTML content of the page to show in the inline frame.

Reference [iframe srdoc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your iframe `src` is targeting the same domain as your main page. Otherwise you are not allowed to access iframe content. This is called XSS (Cross Site Scripting) and it's prevented by major browsers.

If your iframe source is on the same domain and you still can't access it's content make sure to set a `setTimeout` waiting for iframe content to be loaded because iframe content start loading after the main page is loaded.